# Extract Spherical coordinates of panorama from camera pose information and panorama (+pixel) size for correct position in a 3D space.

Tags: 3d, spherical-coordinates, projection, conformal-geometry, spherical-geometry

I am working with spherical image representation. I have the following camera pose information:

[pose.rotation.x, pose.rotation.y, pose.rotation.z, pose.rotation.w],
[pose.translation.x, pose.translation.y, pose.translation.z].

I suppose the first step to do here is find the camera intrinsic matrix? The other input I have is a panoramic image (stitched together using images taken from the above mentioned camera). The panorama comes with the following information:

[image width, image height, pixel width, pixel height].

I want to map the camera and the panorama in terms of spherical or cartesian coordinates in a common coordinate system.

Comment: I'm sure that there is a maths problem underlying this, but currently we have to negotiate non-maths things to get at it ("E57 file", "3D point cloud"). So it would be helpful if you could translate the problem to a purely maths one (or at leaast more maths-ey!).

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. 
Let me break it down. A camera was used to take images of a scene. The camera only rotates in place to take images and stitches them together to get a panorama.
Now the information I have is the camera's pose information (translation + rotation matrix) and I have the panorama width + height and the pixel width + height. What I want to know is how I can map the panorama in 3D coordinates (be it spherical coordinates or cartesian coordinates).

Comment: You should edits your question to make it self-contained and easy to read first-go, rather than clarifying in the comments.

Comment: @user1729 I have edited my question. I hope it tells a clear mathematical angle now. Can you shed some light on the possible solution?